# Compute mean over specific levels of factor in R

Tags: r, nested

I feel like this should not be as difficult as it has been for me, so I have resorted to the mass intelligence that is StackOverflow. Thanks for helping!!

I have the following data:

[image]

This is just an example for one person, it is for about 20 people and in 4 conditions.

What I would like to do, is simply compute the mean change from baseline for the different levels of time. For **each person in each condition**, there should be a baseline value consisting of the mean from pre+base1+base2, to be subtracted from the nosetip value.
For this new change to baseline variable there should then be a time bin1 with the mean from stim1-stim6 change to baseline, bin2 with mean from stim7-12 change to baseline and a mean change to baseline for the recovery phase.

So what I need is a new df that contains these 3 means for every person in every condition.

Generally, what is the best way to summarise specific values/levels of one factor? So far I have tried

```
df_bin$base_mean <- mean(df_bin$time=="pre", df_bin$time=="base1", df_bin$time=="base2", na.rm=TRUE)

df_bin1 <- subset(df_adults, time=="stim1", time=="stim2", time=="stim3", time=="stim4", time=="stim5",time=="stim6")
```

but keep getting error messages.

Thank you so much for reading!

***Edit
Using dput function as suggested by @GregorThomas produces this:

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("AUK102", "AUK103"), class = "factor"), cond_f = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("artificial", 
"babble", "cry", "laugh"), class = "factor"), phase = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("baseline", "break", 
"pre", "recovery", "stimulus"), class = "factor"), time = structure(c(10L, 
9L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 17L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L), .Label = c("base1", 
"base2", "bre1", "bre2", "bre3", "bre4", "bre5", "pre", "pre_30", 
"pre_60", "rec1", "rec2", "rec3", "rec4", "rec5", "rec6", "stim1", 
"stim10", "stim11", "stim12", "stim2", "stim3", "stim4", "stim5", 
"stim6", "stim7", "stim8", "stim9"), class = "factor"), nosetip = c(34, 
34.1, 34.6, 34.3, 34.4, 34.4, 34.4, 34.3, 34.4, 34.1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Personally, I find this a bit confusing, but hope it might help you

Comment: Please share a sample of your data as copy/pasteable text, not as a picture. `dput(df_bin[1:10, ])` would give us the first 10 rows, including all class and structure information. Choose a suitable subset to illustrate the problem.

Comment: The `dput` looks perfect. Anyone can copy/paste it into R to create a sample of your data. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you'd like. I added all the results to the original data, but if you'd prefer one line per "phase 2", you can change the last `mutate` to `summarize`.

```
library(dplyr)
df_bin %>%
  mutate(
    phase2 = case_when(
      time %in% paste0("stim", 1:6) ~ "bin1",
      time %in% paste0("stim", 7:12) ~ "bin2",
      TRUE ~ as.character(phase)
    )
  ) %>%
  group_by(ID, cond_f, phase2) %>%
  mutate(
    phase2_mean = mean(nosetip)
  ) %>%
  group_by(ID, cond_f) %>%
  mutate(
    base_mean = first(phase2_mean[phase == "baseline"]),
    change_from_base = phase2_mean - base_mean
  ) %>%
  as.data.frame
#        ID cond_f    phase   time nosetip   phase2 phase2_mean base_mean change_from_base
# 1  AUK102 babble      pre pre_60    34.0      pre    34.05000  34.43333       -0.3833333
# 2  AUK102 babble      pre pre_30    34.1      pre    34.05000  34.43333       -0.3833333
# 3  AUK102 babble baseline    pre    34.6 baseline    34.43333  34.43333        0.0000000
# 4  AUK102 babble baseline  base1    34.3 baseline    34.43333  34.43333        0.0000000
# 5  AUK102 babble baseline  base2    34.4 baseline    34.43333  34.43333        0.0000000
# 6  AUK102 babble stimulus  stim1    34.4 stim 1-6    34.32000  34.43333       -0.1133333
# 7  AUK102 babble stimulus  stim2    34.4 stim 1-6    34.32000  34.43333       -0.1133333
# 8  AUK102 babble stimulus  stim3    34.3 stim 1-6    34.32000  34.43333       -0.1133333
# 9  AUK102 babble stimulus  stim4    34.4 stim 1-6    34.32000  34.43333       -0.1133333
# 10 AUK102 babble stimulus  stim5    34.1 stim 1-6    34.32000  34.43333       -0.1133333
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This partially does what I need! What I would need instead of the phase2_mean is a variable that has the nosetip - base_mean = change_from_base. So that I can then compute the mean but also the maximum change from baseline for each individual stimulus. Sorry, if I did not explain this well before! Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Sure, feel free to change `phase2_mean` to `nosetip` in the `change_from_base` definition. Doesn't sound like you need any more help!

Comment: The problem I have with this, is that the phase2_mean is not actually the mean. In the output in your answer this is 34.4 for the baseline, while the actual mean should be higher. Similarly with the mean across the two pre-values, this should be 34.05. How do I get the mean computed correctly? What does the first mean in first(phase2_mean[phase == "baseline"])

Comment: Everything is computed correctly. Tibbles default to print only 3 significant digits. We can covert to data.frame to easily see more digits -- see updates.

Comment: As for the `first` - `phase2_mean[phase == "baseline"]` gives all values of `phase2_mean` where `phase == "baseline"`. There are 3 identical values that match that, because there are 3 baseline rows. We pick the `first` of those identical values to put for all values in the `base_mean` column--it doesn't matter which one we pick as they are all the same, but `dplyr` needs us to pick one. Though that column is just there to "show our work"--it isn't really needed. If you wanted you could skip that step and go directly to `change_from_base = nosetip - first(phase2_mean[phase == "baseline"])`.